# Having an issue between < and <=

Tags: java

My question is the following, I've noticed that sometimes in the following code you need to use a < and sometimes its <=.

```
count < numbers.length
count <= numbers.length
```

Do we only use the <= if it is length()???

Comment: `<` means strictly less-than, `<=` means less-than *or* equal to. I suggest you read up on Java operators here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: look for whether you start counting from 1 or from 0.  compare `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)`  to  `for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.length; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have an array `arr` of numbers and you want to make some operation on every each one of them.

Array has `n` elements in it. That means that first index (in java and most programming languages) would be `0`
 and the last `n-1`.

To get each one of elements of `arr` one would write for loop like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; < i++ ) {
    arr[i]; // do something with it
}
```

So you basically count: `0th element, 1st element ... n-1th` element.

You could also write the same loop like that:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++ ) {
    arr[i-1]; // remember java indexing from 0 ?
}
```

Then you count more human-like: `1st element, 2nd, 3rd ... n-th`.

In both loops number of iterations is exactly n so they behave the same way functionally, but in computer science indexing from 0 is natural for many reasons so the former is the preferable way.

Answer (score 5):

`<` would allow count to go up to `numbers.length - 1` (inclusively)

`<=` would allow it to go up to `numbers.length` (again, inclusively)

Usually when iterating over an array etc., you use `< a.length` if you want to iterate from 0 (i.e. `for (i=0 ....)` ) and `<= a.length` if you start from 1 (i.e. `for (i=1 ...)`).

Either choice is fine, so long as you remain consistent throughout your program. Note that starting from `0` to `< length` is usually the practice preffered.